# Reduce image size, but keep maximum quality/resolution?

Tags: gdi+, resolution, image-resizing, asp.net-3.5

I'm resizing an image using `bitmap.GetThumbnailImage()` however I seem to be losing image quality/resolution. For example the original image was 300dpi resolution, and the resized 1 is much smaller.

How can I retain the image resolution when resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I use to reduce my images. The quality is excellent.

```
    private static Image ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

Here's how I use it:

```
        int length = (int)stream.Length;
        byte[] tempImage = new byte[length];
        stream.Read(tempImage, 0, length);

        var image = new Bitmap(stream);
        var resizedImage = ResizeImage(image, new Size(300, 300));
```

Holler if you need help getting it running.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at setting the [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e.aspx) (MSDN link)

You should also take a look at this link: [Create High Quality Thumbnail - Resize Image Dynamically](http://www.webcosmoforums.com/asp/321-create-high-quality-thumbnail-resize-image-dynamically-asp-net-c-code.html)

Essentially, you have code that looks similar to the following:
Bitmap imageToScale = new bitmap( //finish this with the image you want to reduce

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight);  

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
{
    graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.DrawImageimageToScale, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
    bitmap.Save(memoryStreamNew, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
} 

bitmap.Save( //finish this depending on if you want to save to a file location, stream, etc...
```